# Move windows viewpoint down when clicking on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When clicking on the more toggle the rest of the text will show. For smaller screen, we need to scroll down to read all the text. Is there a way to move the viewpoint down few pixels when clicking on more toggle? I wish it to slide down to the header of article after clicking on more. I have margin on top of article wrapper and do not want to remove that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ellipsestext = "...",
    moretext = "More",
    lesstext = "Less",
    showChar;
  $('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    showChar = content.search(/<!\-\-\s*break\s*\-\->/);
    if (content.length > showChar && showChar != -1) {

      var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
      var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

      var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

      $(this).html(html);
    }

  });

  $(".morelink").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
      $(this).removeClass("less");
      $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("less");
      $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
#first article {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: rgba(14, 0, 0, 0.3);
 width: 860px;;
 float: right; 
 margin-bottom: 95px;
 margin-top: 150px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-top: 20px;
}

nav#menu {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 5;
 width: 100%;
 top:0%;
 text-align: center;
 height: 90px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
 background-color: rgba(14, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


nav#menu a {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-indent: -9999px;
  color: #fff;
}

nav#menu li {
 display:block;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 padding: 1em;
 font-weight: 900;
 font-family: 'Sorts Mill Goudy', serif;
 text-align: center;
 height: 3em;
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 /*border: solid 1px #fff;*/
 }

nav#menu ul {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 85px;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#7E7E7E7E', EndColorStr='#7E7E7E7E');*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a class="first" href="#f">Home1</a></li>
<li><a class="first" href="#f">Home2</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>


<section id="first" class="story" data-speed="4" data-type="background"  >     
<div id="wrapper">

<article>
      
<div class="comment more">
 <h2>Header</h2>
Son had talks with at least one lender before scrapping the plan at least three months ago when he could not agree with the overseas partner on financing conditions, the people said, asking not to be identified because they are not authorized to discuss the matter.  <!-- break -->
  
While it was the top possible deal earlier this year, Son is no longer considering using that partner, the people said without elaborating.
Concerns about debt and struggling U.S. unit Sprint Corp. have driven SoftBank’s market value down to about $64 billion, or less than the stakes it holds in companies including Alibaba Group Holding Ltd. and Yahoo Japan Corp. A deal excluding Son’s 19.3 percent stake would be the biggest management buyout ever, according to data compiled by Bloomberg.
</div>
  
</article>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scroll with jQuery using the method [scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/).

```
// Example : Scroll the window at 450px from the top
$(window).scrollTop(450);
```

You can add this line after the code on your toggle button (just after `$(this).prev().toggle();`). If you change your css or your layout, you may have to use a different value for the `scrollTop`.

If you want to scroll only when you click on `more` (and not on `less`), you can add the code just after `$(this).html(moretext);`

Comment: Thank you. I did as you said.   $(this).html(html); $(window).scrollTop(450); but when I click on more toggle it is still staying the same. Does not move my article up. I want my article to have margin top 240px as it is right now, but when clicking on more toggle to show more text, the article wrapper will move up. Is it possible to do?

Comment: When I added $(window).scrollTop(450); it added the scrollTop 450px from top right away when I visit the site. Which is not how I wanted. I want it to get 450px scroll top after clicking the more toggle. Sorry for long explanation.

Comment: Oh sorry. Wrong line. I edited my response. I was lost in your code.

Comment: I have made the changes you edited. When I added $(this).html(more text); $(window).scrollTop(450); it works, but in wrong way. it moves up 450px only when I click on "less". When I click on "more" nothing happen. :( What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm afraid your code is pretty weird. Try to put the code after `$(this).html(lesstext);`

Comment: I added the code after $(this).html(less text);. When I click on "more" it moves up to the home1. Even I added less pixel or more pixel it won't follow. Strange.. :(

Comment: I got the correct help from you, and I will vote this as correct Thank you.:) But there is still something not working correctly. It is working now only for Home1, for other pages it will just move back up to the Home1.